# Do I have to give the professor my Pokemon in order to evolve?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know that you can transfer pokemon to the professor in exchange for candies but do you always have to do that or once you have the required amount of candies just evolve your pokemon right off the bat?

Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused by.

Comment: do i absolutely need to transfer to evolve or if i have the required amount of candies can i just evolve ?

Comment: Yes if you have enough candies, you can evolve a pokemon. Trading to the professor only gives you more candies to use.

Answer (score 4):

If you have enough candies (for example, let's say Oddish candies), then you can evolve your Oddish to a Gloom.

Now let's say we want to transfer an Oddish to the professor. If you do so, you will receive a single Oddish candy. As such, no, you do not need to transfer anything to the professor to evolve a Pokemon.